# HTML: relative positioned overlapping elements in TD makes TD too wide

Tags: html

I have code that generates a `TABLE` that contains relative positioned elements causing elements to overlap in a `TD`. The `TD` then appears too wide.

Here's a short example of the table:

```
<html><body>
    <table>
        <tr style="background-color: rgb(221, 255, 221)">
            <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                text1
                <select size="1" style="width: 262px">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>12345</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" size="5" style="position: relative; left: -262px; width: 239px">
                <span style="position: relative; left: -239px">text2</span>

                <input type="text" size="5" style="position: relative; left: -239px">
                <span style="position: relative; left: -239px">text3</span>
                <input type="text" size="5" style="position: relative; left: -239px">
                <span style="position: relative; left: -239px"> </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                info
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body></html>
```

The `input`-element appears above the `select`-element.

Obviously I don't have any widths set in `TD`, `TR` or `TABLE`. So it's the browser that makes the first column too wide. The width of the empty space seems to be the width of the `input`-element.

How can I circumvent this? Basically I want the first column only to be as wide as necessary.

Comment: Can you add a mock-up of the UI you want for this HTML?

Comment: @Naveed Opera 11.50, Firefox 3.6. However, it should work with Chrome and IE, too. What mock-up? The only current problem is the space between the third input element and the right end of the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you want somthing like this:

```
<html><body>
    <table style="width: auto">
        <tr style="background-color: rgb(221, 255, 221)">
            <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                text1
                <select size="1" style="width: 262px">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>12345</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" size="5" style="position: relative; left: -262px; width: 239px; margin-right: -262px;">
                <span style="position: relative; left: -239px">text2</span>

                <input type="text" size="5">
                <span>text3</span>
                <input type="text" size="5">
                <span> </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                info
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body></html>
```

I'm only moving the one you want to place over the select, and compensate with a negative margin.

Else the width of the table cell would have been the same as when you don't use any positioning.

Update 2011-08-11 13:00:

```
<html><body>
    <table style="width: auto">
        <tr style="background-color: rgb(221, 255, 221)">
            <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                text1
                <select size="1" style="width: 262px">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>12345</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" size="5" style="position: relative; left: -262px; width: 239px; margin-right: -242px;">
                <span>text2</span>

                <input type="text" size="5">
                <span>text3</span>
                <input type="text" size="5">
                <span> </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                info
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body></html>
```

I forgot to remove the last position on the "text2"-span.
And after that i had to to change the negative marig-right a bit, so "text2" did not end up on tom of the long input and the select.

Comment: Did you test this? Or on which browser did you test this? Your solution writes the elements after the first `input` over the first `input`. So I see "text2" above the `input`-element, which is above the `select`-element, i.e. three element above one another.